# Set image, title and buttons in the same line of the header of a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I put an image,title and buttons in the same line inside the header of a shiny dashboard? It looks like that the title remains hidden above the buttons but it is supposed to be between image and button since I use `tags$li()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(href = "http://https://www.uow.edu.au/", #   '',
            div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-70px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
                img(src = 'download.png', height = "55px",width="232px")),
            div(style="display: inline; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1600px ;font-size: 22px ;color: black;font-family:Times-New Roman;font-weight: bold; width: 300px;",HTML(mytitle, "<br>")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 1350px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("well", "Welcome")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("info", "Information")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("pswd", "Password")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results"))
            
  ),
  class = "dropdown")

  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px"
                                         ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}"))
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(href = "http://https://www.uow.edu.au/", #   '',
            div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-83px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
                img(src = 'YBS.png', height = "125px",width="232px")),
            div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 800px ;font-size: 58px ;color: black;font-family:Times-New Roman;font-weight: bold; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
            div(style="display: inline;margin-top:25px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 800px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("well", "Welcome")),
            div(style="display: inline;margin-top:15px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("info", "Information")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("pswd", "Password")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project")),
            div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results"))
            
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px"
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}"))
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
  }
  )
)
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks could you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587419/adapt-the-position-of-image-actionbuttons-and-totle-in-header-of-shinydashboard