# Adapt the position of image, actionbuttons and tιtle in header of shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny app below in which I want to put in the header an image, a title and four actionbuttons like in the attached screenshot. The 4 buttons should be below the title and not cover the image. How can I adapt it? Does it depend on screen resolution? The font and font sizes should not change.

[image]

It should be like:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)


mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-83px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
        img(src = 'logo-primary-linen.png', height = "125px",width="232px")),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:15px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("info", "Information", 
                                                                                                                          style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6"))
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Information", tabName = "info", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Run Project", tabName = "rp", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )          ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      

      
      tabItems(
        
        tabItem("info"
                
        ),
        tabItem("conse"
                ),
        tabItem("rp"),
        tabItem("res"
                )
      )
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")


  }
  )
)
```

Comment: I would suggest to replace your manual element alignment with the layout functions from shiny (see second page: https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/shiny.pdf). Use a `fluidRow` for your title and another with 4 columns for your buttons.

Comment: i see...but could you provide a working example?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64942699/set-image-title-and-buttons-in-the-same-line-of-the-header-of-a-shiny-dashboard/64944627?noredirect=1#comment115963793_64944627) is not working?  Please clarify.

Comment: For some reason it is displayed like you see in the first attached screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much left  padding was pushing it to the right.  Try this

```
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style = "margin-left:-15px;margin-bottom:-78px;margin-top:-15px;padding: 0px 1190px 0px 0px ; width: 290px;",
        img(src = 'UOW.png', height = "155px",width="232px")),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 50px 0px 700px ;font-size: 44px ;color:#001641;font-family:Chronicle Display Light; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    
    div(style="display: inline; margin-top:15px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 700px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("info", "Information", 
                                                                                                                          style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results", 
                                                                                                         style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6"))
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Information", tabName = "info", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Run Project", tabName = "rp", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )          ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      
      
      
      tabItems(
        
        tabItem("info"
                
        ),
        tabItem("conse"
        ),
        tabItem("rp"),
        tabItem("res"
        )
      )
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    
  }
  )
)
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks that works. I think that the image is a little bigger than the header section in the botton. can u see that? how can I adjust it?

Comment: Try `margin-bottom:-78px;` instead of `margin-bottom:-83px;`.  Code is updated.